# Uncompressing gzip file

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I have compressed a folder using following command:

```
tar czvf arch.tar.gz dirname/
```

When I try to uncompress it using following command

```
tar xvfz arch.tar.gz
```

then it uncompress folder but contents of folder remains compressed.

Before compression there were files in folder like index.php. Now after uncompressing there is a file `index.php.gz`

Please advice me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got compressed files in your output from tar, it's because they were compressed going in.  You can verify with with `tar tzvf arch.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, in my Ubuntu this commands run correct.

```
strangeman@etalon:~$ tar czvf test.tar.gz test/
test/
test/file1
test/file2
test/file3
test/file4
test/file5
test/file6
test/file7
test/file8
test/file9
test/file0
strangeman@etalon:~$  tar xvfz test.tar.gz
test/
test/file1
test/file2
test/file3
test/file4
test/file5
test/file6
test/file7
test/file8
test/file9
test/file0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies with the order you used for the tar switches. You ran:

```
tar xvfz arch.tar.gz
```

A correct ordering would leave the **f** switch last:

```
tar zxvf arch.tar.gz
```

This way, arch.tar.gz is an argument to **f**. I don't think you can put any other switch after **f** and get any predictable behavior across different **tar** implementations.